# Symfony - dropdown list with entity.propriety filter

Tags: symfony, filter, dropdown

i have 3 entities named Answer, Skill and Jointure.

Answer and Skill are linked to Jointure with a ManyToOne relation.

I display them in twig like that :

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @var JointureRepository
     */

    public function __construct(JointureRepository $repository, ObjectManager $em)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $JointureRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Jointure::class);
        $arrJointures = $JointureRepository->findAll();
        $this->em->flush();

        return $this->render('pages/home.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
            'jointure' => $arrJointures,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and in my twig view :

```
{% for object in jointure %}
    {% for skill in object.skills %}   
        {{skill.label}}  
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've created a dropdown button who list all the skill.label properties who exists like that :

EDIT : Here my twig button :

```
            <div class="form-group ">
            <select id="inputState " class="form-control">
              <option selected>Compétence</option>
              {% for object in jointure %}
              {% for skill in object.skills %}
              <option>{{skill.label}}</option>
              {% endfor %}
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to show / display all answer.userEmail who have this related skill.label in a view in my template.I have to use EntityType ? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start using Symfony Forms. Here is documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html. It is not that simple at the beginning but it definitely worith it. Then you will be able to use `EntityType` https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html